# I want to display real-time incoming data on the chart. But I don't know what to do

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

Currently, the line chart of ng2-charts is used by the angular.
But I don't know how to make a graph with real-time data.

lineChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
{ data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 100, 125],
label: ''
}
];

Comment: Are you any setInterval function for getting realtime data's

Answer (score 0):

Use some socket to connect and see the data in realtime.
A good tool to do this is the Firebase Realtime Database, that you are allowed to write and read data in realtime.

> Store and sync data with our NoSQL cloud database. Data is synced across all clients in realtime, and remains available when your app goes offline.
>
> The Firebase Realtime Database is a cloud-hosted database. Data is
> stored as JSON and synchronized in realtime to every connected client.
> When you build cross-platform apps with our iOS, Android, and
> JavaScript SDKs, all of your clients share one Realtime Database
> instance and automatically receive updates with the newest data.

Here's [a link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database)!

Comment: I am receiving data in real time.
But I don't know how to put the data in.

Comment: Put the function that updates your chart inside the onValueChanged of Firebase